# HTTP Post not working with FreeRTOS task, but does work with a function

Tags: c, api, http-post, scheduled-tasks, freertos

I am trying to update values to a database, but when I try to do so using RTOS tasks, it does not work, but it does work by calling a function inside a while loop.

I am having trouble understanding why calling HTTP POST works inside a function, but not inside a task. The picture below has the output of the monitor when calling HTTP post from a task.

The reason I want to use a task instead of a function is because I would like for my database to update every 30 seconds.

Here is the code that updates the database this does not work:

```
void updateDB_task(void *arg){


    while(1){
    xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();
    vTaskDelayUntil(&xLastWakeTime, (30000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS));


    if(xSemaphoreTake(xMutex,0) ==pdTRUE){
        esp_http_client_config_t config = {
            .url = "http://httpbin.org/get", //this gets overwritten later, we can keep as is
        };
    esp_http_client_handle_t client = esp_http_client_init(&config);
    esp_err_t err = esp_http_client_open(client, 0);

    char *URL = "localhost/post-sensor-readings.php";

        esp_http_client_set_url(client, URL);
        esp_http_client_set_method(client, HTTP_METHOD_POST);
        esp_http_client_set_header(client, "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        char tempSensor[10];
        char humiditySensor[10];
        char moistureSensor[10];
        char nitrogenSensor[10];
        char potassiumSensor[10];
        char phosphorousSensor[10];
        char output_buffer[MAX_HTTP_OUTPUT_BUFFER] = {0};


        char  post_data[250];
        char *post_header ="api_key=tPmAT5Ab3j7F9";

        sprintf(tempSensor, "%d", temphumValue.temperature);
        sprintf(humiditySensor, "%d", temphumValue.humidity);
        sprintf(moistureSensor, "%d", moistureValue.soilMoisture);
        sprintf(nitrogenSensor, "%d", npkSensor.nitrogenReading);
        sprintf(potassiumSensor, "%d", npkSensor.potassiumReading);
        sprintf(phosphorousSensor, "%d", npkSensor.phosphorousReading);




        strcpy(post_data, post_header);
        printf("Printing First Concatenation: %s\n", post_data);

        strcat(post_data, temphumValue.tempEntry);
        strcat(post_data, tempSensor);
        printf("Printing First Concatenation (temperature): %s\n", post_data);

        strcat(post_data, temphumValue.humidityEntry);
        strcat(post_data, humiditySensor);
        printf("Printing 2nd Concatenation (humidity): %s\n", post_data);

        strcat(post_data, moistureValue.soilEntry);
        strcat(post_data, moistureSensor);
        printf("Printing third Concatenation (moisture): %s\n", post_data);

        strcat(post_data, npkSensor.nitrogenEntry);
        strcat(post_data, nitrogenSensor);
        printf("Printing 4th Concatenation (nitrogen): %s\n", post_data);

        strcat(post_data, npkSensor.potassiumEntry);
        strcat(post_data, potassiumSensor);
        printf("Printing 5th Concatenation (potassium): %s\n", post_data);


        strcat(post_data, npkSensor.phosphorousEntry);
        strcat(post_data, phosphorousSensor);
        printf("Printing 6th Concatenation (phosphorous): %s\n", post_data);
        printf("The value of the post header:%s\n",post_data);

        err = esp_http_client_open(client, strlen(post_data));
            if (err != ESP_OK) {
                ESP_LOGE(TAG2, "Failed to open HTTP connection: %s", esp_err_to_name(err));
            } else {
                int wlen = esp_http_client_write(client, post_data, strlen(post_data));
                if (wlen < 0) {
                    ESP_LOGE(TAG2, "Write failed");
                }
                int data_read = esp_http_client_read_response(client, output_buffer, MAX_HTTP_OUTPUT_BUFFER);
                if (data_read >= 0) {
                    ESP_LOGI(TAG2, "HTTP GET Status = %d, content_length = %d",
                    esp_http_client_get_status_code(client),
                    esp_http_client_get_content_length(client));
                    ESP_LOG_BUFFER_HEX(TAG2, output_buffer, strlen(output_buffer));
                } else {
                    ESP_LOGE(TAG2, "Failed to read response");
                }
        }
            xSemaphoreGive(xMutex);
            esp_http_client_cleanup(client);


    }

    vTaskDelay(3000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

}
     vTaskDelete(NULL);
}/*
```

This is how its called in main:

```
void app_main() {

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_init());
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ESP_WIFI_MODE_STA");
    wifi_init_sta();
    xMutex = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();


    xTaskCreate(soilHumidity_task, "soil moisture  task", 2048, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, NULL);

    xTaskCreate(temperature_task, "temperature task", 2048, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(npk_Task, "npk task", 2048, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(updateDB_task, "database task", 2048, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, NULL);

}
```

This is the code that does work, but it does so using a function and a while loop:

```
void updateDB_task(void){

    char output_buffer[MAX_HTTP_OUTPUT_BUFFER] = {0};
    esp_http_client_config_t config = {
        .url = "http://httpbin.org/get", //this gets overwritten later, we can keep as is
    };
    esp_http_client_handle_t client = esp_http_client_init(&config);
    esp_err_t err = esp_http_client_open(client, 0);

    char  post_data[250];
    char *post_header ="api_key=tPmAT5Ab3j7F9";


    sprintf(tempSensor, "%d", temperature);
    sprintf(humiditySensor, "%d", humidity);
    sprintf(nitrogenSensor, "%d", nitrogenReading);
    sprintf(potassiumSensor, "%d", potassiumReading);
    sprintf(phosphorousSensor, "%d", phosphorousReading);

    strcpy(post_data, post_header);

    strcat(post_data, tempEntry);
    strcat(post_data, tempSensor);

    strcat(post_data, humidityEntry);
    strcat(post_data, humiditySensor);

    strcat(post_data, soilEntry);
    strcat(post_data, moistureSensor);

    strcat(post_data, nitrogenEntry);
    strcat(post_data, nitrogenSensor);

    strcat(post_data, potassiumEntry);
    strcat(post_data, potassiumSensor);


    strcat(post_data, phosphorousEntry);
    strcat(post_data, phosphorousSensor);


    esp_http_client_set_url(client, URL);
    esp_http_client_set_method(client, HTTP_METHOD_POST);
    esp_http_client_set_header(client, "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    printf("The value of the post header:%s\n",post_data);

    err = esp_http_client_open(client, strlen(post_data));
    if (err != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG2, "Failed to open HTTP connection: %s", esp_err_to_name(err));
    } else {
        int wlen = esp_http_client_write(client, post_data, strlen(post_data));
        if (wlen < 0) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG2, "Write failed");
        }
        int data_read = esp_http_client_read_response(client, output_buffer, MAX_HTTP_OUTPUT_BUFFER);
        if (data_read >= 0) {
            ESP_LOGI(TAG2, "HTTP GET Status = %d, content_length = %d",
            esp_http_client_get_status_code(client),
            esp_http_client_get_content_length(client));
            ESP_LOG_BUFFER_HEX(TAG2, output_buffer, strlen(output_buffer));
        } else {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG2, "Failed to read response");
        }
    }

    esp_http_client_cleanup(client);
}
```

This is how its called in main:

```
=
void app_main() {

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_init());
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ESP_WIFI_MODE_STA");
    wifi_init_sta();
    xTaskCreate(soilHumidity_task, "soil moisture  task", 2048, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, NULL);

    xTaskCreate(temperature_task, "temperature task", 2048, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, NULL);

//  xTaskCreate(updateDB_task, "databse task", 2048, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, NULL);
    while(1){

        updateDB_task();
    }
}
```

The latter implementation updates mySql database, and when printing to the monitor, it does not give the weird output as shown in the figure below.

[image: Console when I am trying to Call HTTP post via tasks]

I've tried shuffling the position of xSemaphoreGive(xMutex); but other than that I am lost, When I print the   post_data string, the string concatanates fine, but when I call the esp_http_client functions, my app seems to crash.

Comment: Task stack size?

Comment: @MartinJames 2048, it’s in the xtaskCreate() definitions.

Comment: Yeah, but is that enough?